# Doubts about how to read XML with Linq

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I´m trying read XML from url and i was reading some tutorial with linq and I don´t know how read the xml.

The connection with httpclient was sucessfully showing xml in textbox. Once I saw that it worked,I tried read the XML.I show you the xml and code used:

```html
 <response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XML-Schema-instance" version="1.2" 
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://aviationweather.gov/adds/schema/metar1_2.xsd">
<request_index>20823075</request_index>
<data_source name="metars"/>
<request type="retrieve"/>
<errors/>
<warnings/>
<time_taken_ms>1</time_taken_ms>
<data num_results="1">
<METAR>
<raw_text>
KJFK 231651Z 05008KT 10SM FEW190 SCT250 24/08 A3025 RMK AO2 SLP244 T02390078
</raw_text>
```

```
 Dim url As String = "http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=" & airport & "&hoursBeforeNow=1"

    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
    Dim request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)

    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.SendAsync(request)

    Dim responseurl As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync

    Dim metarxml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(url)

    Dim metar = From r In metarxml.Descendants("METAR")
                Select New{raw_text=r.element("raw_text").value}
    For Each r In metarxml
        metarresultxt.Text(r.raw_text)
    Next
```

Somebody could help me with code?.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch just `raw_text`, you can do that like this:-

```
Dim result As String = (From x In xdoc.Descendants("METAR")
                     Select x.Element("raw_text").Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Although, I am not sure if you have multiple `raw_text`, `METAR` or `data` tags because you have not posted the complete XML in which case query will change accordingly.

**Update:**

Okay as per your posted XML probably you need value of all the elements inside `METAR`. You can project them as anonymous type and use `FirstOrDefault` since you have just 1 `METAR` node:-

```
Dim result = (From x In xdoc.Descendants("METAR")
              Select New With {Key .rawText = x.Element("raw_text").Value,
                               Key .stationId = x.Element("station_id").Value
                               ...and so on
                              }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Finally you can access it's properties directly:-

```
Console.WriteLine(result.rawText)
Console.WriteLine(result.stationId)
```

Comment: http://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=lemd&hoursBeforeNow=0.5

Comment: Thanks so much for you reply Rahul. I didn´t posted all XML because it was an example to do it with followings tags.Anyway, i post the link with complete XML:

http://www.aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=kjfk&hoursBeforeNow=0.5

Comment: I´m going to try it!! Thanks in advance Rahul!

Comment: Hello Rahul,When i try with the update but there is a problem. It show a error: Cannot open "http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=" & airport & "&hoursBeforeNow=0.5" The uri parameter must bea file system relative path. Then I tried with new windows forms project, and it works.I don´t know what it happens.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve a question about result. I´ve tried adapt it and i did a test but it appears "If Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached Then Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()". I don´t know what could be wrong.I paste all code used:

```
    Dim airport As String = stationidtxt.Text
    Dim url As String = "http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=" & airport & "&hoursBeforeNow=0.5"



    If DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Internet connection is required.Please,enable cellular or WiFi")
        Return
    End If


    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(stationidtxt.Text.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please, I need the ICAO Station to get weather data")
        Return
    End If


    Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()


    Dim request As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url)


    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.SendAsync(request)
    Dim responseurl As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync

    If HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        GoTo Lineaconexion
    ElseIf HttpStatusCode.BadRequest Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please,check the connectivity")
    End If
```

Lineaconexion:

```
Dim metarxml As XDocument = XDocument.Load(url)
    Dim metar = (From x In metarxml.Descendants("METAR")
          Select New With {Key .rawtext = x.Element("raw_text").Value,
                           Key .latitude = x.Element("latitude").Value
                          }).FirstOrDefault()

    metarresultxt.Text = metar.rawtext
    latitudetxt.Text = metar.latitude

End Sub
```